# How can I use a variable to include a linked image?

Tags: wp-admin

I have a help page added to my admin, with screenshots of various config settings.

The screenshots are located in a subfolder (several levels deep) of the theme.

Currently, to insert linked thumbnails I'm using this...

```
<a href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/path_to/image.png">
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/path_to/image.png"></a>
```

For simplicity, I'm wondering if/how I can use a $variable to set the path to the appropriate subfolder, and use it (rather than the full path).

My limited knowledge is enough to echo such an url...

```
$url = bloginfo('template_directory'). '/extras/config/screenshots/plugins';

echo $url;
```

But I don't know enough to use it to add the image and link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most of the way there, you simply have to echo it into the include:

```
<a href="<?php echo $url;?>/image.png"><img src="<?php echo $url;?>/image.png"></a>
```

If you are already echoing this whole line, then you simply concatenate the variable:

```
echo '<a href="'.$url.'/image.png"><img src="'.$url.'/image.png"></a>'
```

Do some reading on PHP "concatenation" :)

Comment: thanks. I'd tried that initially and it didn't work (still doesn't). I wonder whether it's because I'm 'using php within php' (it's added to a /functions .php file - I'll edit my original post to make clear).

Comment: I understand, have edited my answer. Of course the paths will have to be correct, but the principle is as I indicated :)

Comment: thanks. as suggested, I'll read more. The issue I'm getting is that '/extras/config/screenshots/plugins' is being appended to root and the part-path to the theme directory is absent.

Comment: Sorry I'm not following you. You asked if you can use a variable to hold a path (you can) and I showed how to use it "inside" and "outside" of PHP. If you need something else please edit your question.

Comment: Thanks. If, when creating the variable, I change '$url = bloginfo' (without quotes) to '$url = get_bloginfo' (without quotes), your code works ok. But when using '$url = bloginfo' (without quotes), the url/src is as-noted in an earlier comment minus the path to the template directory. So, acceptance applied. Thanks. ;-)